# Android 12 Splash Screen beta not modifiable

Tags: android, themes, splash-screen

I am trying to create splash screen and set it as a Splash theme its not picking up the background color and even the branded icon and showing default screen with android rounded logo with grey background.

**theme.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.BaseMVVM" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
      
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.BaseMVVM.Initial" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground" tools:targetApi="s">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" tools:targetApi="s">@drawable/ic_baseline_article_24</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage" tools:targetApi="s">@drawable/ic_baseline_article_24</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.BaseMVVM</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Menifest:**

```
 <activity
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BaseMVVM.Initial"
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**SplashActivity:**

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            delay(2000)
            gotoHomeActivity()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem by by adding the android namespace in the the Splash.xml items which makes it target android 12 and above only.

```
   <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground" tools:targetApi="s">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" tools:targetApi="s">@drawable/ic_baseline_article_24</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage" tools:targetApi="s">@drawable/ic_baseline_article_24</item>
```

When the android attribute is used the splash screen wont be available to lower levels of android .
To use the Compatibility API,omit the android attribute for the items and use it like this:

```
   <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground" >@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" >@drawable/ic_baseline_article_24</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBrandingImage" >@drawable/ic_baseline_article_24</item>
```

The [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate) has a guide too